# jQuery DOM implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-events

I have heard people say jQuery uses a special event library instead of the default DOM implementation that browsers provide.

What exactly does it mean and practically speaking can you provide some examples to highlight the same ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Very generally*, jQuery has a system where a single handler is attached to the element that  retains a reference to the element via closure.

When the event occurs on the element, it invokes a more generic handler (`jQuery.event.handle`) from the context of that element, which passes on the `event` object it received.

That handler analyzes the event, does a lookup of the element in `jQuery.cache` via that element's `jQuery1234567...` *expando property*, and invokes the proper handler(s) that are also stored in that element's `jQuery.cache` entry.

The upshot is that the only handler that is *actually* attached to the element is this lightweight one that `jQuery` itself creates and attaches. Therefore it will never cause memory leaks in IE *due to any sort of circular references to DOM elements*.

---

One thing that you ***must*** know when using `jQuery` to manage your event handlers is that the ***only*** link between an element and its entry in `jQuery.cache` is that expando property.

If you have some code that strays outside `jQuery` to remove elements from the DOM, then `jQuery` is not notified to remove associated handlers and other data from `jQuery.cache`, causing its own memory leak that isn't limited to old versions of IE.

So if you have a section of `HTML` that has handlers attached via `jQuery`, and you do something like this:

```
element_container.innerHTML = '';
```

...now any entries in `jQuery.cache` that relate to the elements removed are orphaned, and will likely exist as long as the browser window remains open.

So if you use `jQuery` to manage event binding, be sure to stay within the API when destroying elements so that `jQuery` can manage and clean up `jQuery.cache` when necessary.

---

**EDIT:** I had the handlers flipped around. Generally same concept though.

---

```
/*
   Here we bind 4 handlers to the same element.
*/

var elem = $('#my_elem');

  // This first call to .bind() binds a generic handler to `#my_elem`.
  // Then it places the handler we passed in jQuery.cache.
elem.bind( 'click', function() { alert( 'click 1' ); } );

  // Generic handler already exists, so these handlers are 
  //    just added to jQuery.cache.
elem.bind( 'click', function() { alert( 'click 2' ); } );
elem.bind( 'mouseenter', function() { alert( 'mouseenter 1' ); } );
elem.bind( 'mouseleave', function() { alert( 'mouseleave 1' ); } );
```

```
/*
    This is a simplified example of the binding of the generic handler. Notice
       that it actually invokes an internal function.
*/

elem[0].addEventListener( 'click', function( e ) {
    _internal_handler.apply( elem, arguments );
}, false);
```

```
/*
    This is a simplified example of the internal function.
*/

_internal_handler( e ) {
      // Find out the type of event, like "click", or whatever
    var event_type = e.type;  

      // Get this element's data from jQuery.cache
    var data = jQuery.data( this );

       // If data was found...
    if( data ) {
          // ...get the "events" stored in the element's data
        var events = data.events; 

          // If events were found, and events has the current type of event...
        if( events && events[ event_type ] ) {

              // ...then data.events[ event_type ] will give us the Array of
              //       handlers for that event type, so iterate the Array,
              //        and fire the handlers.
            for( var i = 0; i < events[ event_type ]; i++; ) {

                  // handler invoked
                events[ event_type ][ i ].call( this, e );  

            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is of course an *extreme* simplification of the code, but generally shows what happens.

Comment: Thx a lot..u have tried your best to explain a difficult concept...Would it be possible for you to explain the first part about handler in more simpler terms..may be with an example or something?

Comment: @testndtv: Basically, jQuery attaches 1 generic handler per element. That generic handler is capable of invoking any of the handlers you bind with jQuery, which are stored in `jQuery.cache`. `jQuery.cache` is like a central repository of all data that jQuery associates with an element. That data includes event handlers. So an event occurs on an element, that element looks to see if it has any handlers in `jQuery.cache`, and if so, it invokes them.

Comment: Ok..cool..2 Questions; 1) Does jQuery attach the generic element to each and every element on the page OR it is on some basis? 2) In the case of mixing DOm and jQuery example you gave, we are just replacing the innerHTML. So how does it clash with the jQuery handling ? I mean we are not deleting or adding element here

Comment: @testndtv: 1) It only adds the generic handler to an element when you bind an event handler to it. So if I do `$('#my_elem').click(function(){...})`, the generic handler is bound to `#my_elem`, and the function you passed to `.click()` is added to `jQuery.cache`. Then if you bind more handlers to the same element, jQuery doesn't need to add the generic one (because it's already there), so all it does is add the handlers you passed to `jQuery.cache`. 2) Imagine we've bound 5 handlers to the same element. That means there's only one handler actually bound to the element (the generic one) and...

Comment: ...there's 5 associated with that element sitting in `jQuery.cache`. Then say we want to get rid of that element. If we call jQuery's `.remove()` method, it takes a look at the *expando property* that was placed on that element, uses the value of that property to look up that element's data in `jQuery.cache`, cleans up (destroys) all the associated data in `jQuery.cache`, then finally removes the element. So that's quite a bit of work that `.remove()` does. But what if we *don't* call `.remove()`, and instead use the DOM directly? None of that data in `jQuery.cache` gets cleaned up, and...

Comment: ...the element no longer exists, so that data has been effectively orphaned. If you open the console and type `jQuery.cache`, you'll see an object that contains a bunch of numeric properties... `1:... 2:... 3:...`. Each one of those numbers corresponds to an element on the page that has received some data from jQuery. The element has its *expando property* that looks like `jQuery3648376269: 2`, where `jQuery3648376269` is the key and `2` is the value of to its entry in `jQuery.cache`. That's the only link between the two. I'll see if I can update my answer with a more visual description.

Comment: Hey patrick..EXCEPTIONAL AND MIND BOGGLING ANSWER TO SAY THE LEAST..I mean the description you have given could not have been any more simpler to understand somewhat difficult concept..If i could, I would have given 1000 votes to you..Anyways, an answer that i think is much better than even the Jquery documentation..

Comment: Even though, i'll accept it..just one last question..In which cases can the memory leak happen..like one is when we remove via DOM method..What are other possibilities?

Comment: @testndtv: Well I'm very glad that it was helpful. :) With respect to memory leaks, it pertains to anything that adds to the data stored in `jQuery.cache`. This includes event handlers, any data set using jQuery's `.data()` or `$.data()` methods, as well as some perhaps unexpected situations where methods like `hide()` store and reference associated information in `jQuery.cache` (though the amount of data is minimal). If you want any of that data cleaned up when you destroy elements, you must use jQuery's methods.

Comment: [Here's an example](http://jsbin.com/ajodet/edit#javascript,live) you can mess with that displays some of the data added to `jQuery.cache` for an element. The jsBin "Real-time preview" is enabled, so go ahead and add more handlers and data to the element and see them appear.

Comment: ...[this one](http://jsbin.com/ajodet/3/edit#javascript,live) shows a little more.

Answer (score 0):

These links might help:

http://docs.jquery.com/Types#Event

http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

Basically, jQuery takes the event types from all the browsers and turns them into a generic event object.